# Is there a way to call a method from MainActivity inside BroadCastReceiver onReceive?

Tags: android, methods, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way to call a method that is in the MainActivity from BroadcastReceiver?

All I am trying to do is to be able to **skip** a song with the **Status Bar Notification**.

AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver 
    android:name="MainActivity$switchButtonListener" />
```

MainActivity:

```
    resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);         

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_remoteviews);

    Notification mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.img_btn_next)
    .setContentTitle("TEST")        
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setContent(notificationView).build();

    //this is the intent that is supposed to be called when the 
    //button is clicked
    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, switchButtonListener.class);
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, 0);

    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeOnFlash, pendingSwitchIntent);

    NotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder);

.....

......


//Method
    public void TestMethod() {  
        Play(2);
    }

......

.....


public static class switchButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private MainActivty mainActivity;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mainActivity = new MainActivty();
        mainActivity.TestMethod();      
    }

}
```

I placed this Log.e("MY_LOG", "" + "REGISTERED") in the onReceive method in BroadcastReceiver and it did show up.

I placed this code Play(2);  in my MainActivity Oncreate method, and it worked fine.  However,

When I placed the same code Play(2);  in TestMethod, it gave me a NullPointerException below.....  What's going on?

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(889): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver main.activity.MainActivity$switchButtonListener: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can someone please help?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: added more logcat

```
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2431)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at main.activity.MainActivity.play(MainActivity.java:402)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at main.activity.MainActivity.TestMethod(MainActivity.java:661)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at main.activity.MainActivity$switchButtonListener.onReceive(MainActivity.java:648)
09-18 06:35:43.864: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2424)
```

Comment: Can you post more of your Logcat, please? There should be some lines beneath the line you post...

Comment: After all, you should be able to just call MainActivity.this.TestMethode() from within the Receiver, as the switchButtonListener is a Inner class.

Comment: It's the static class, so it won't let me add MainActivity.this.TestMethode();  It has to be static class or else the BroadCastReceiver will throw an error.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your `broadcastReceiver` is defined inside your Activity you could try the following:

```
MainActivity.this.TestMethod();
```

That should work

Hope it helps.

Comment: I put that code in, but it says No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope.  Thanks